# Analytic geometry - triangle

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have three points:
A[1, 2]; B[3, 5] and C[5, 7]

I have some random points, like this:
E [4, 4] etc.

I need to check if these random point are a part of the ABC triangle, or not.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember):

```
rmf = RegionMember@Triangle[{{1,2},{3,5},{5,7}}];
```

Random points:

```
pts = RandomReal[7, {10^3, 2}];
```

Use the [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember) function to find out which points are a part of the triangle:

```
Tally[rmf @ pts]
```

> {{False, 972}, {True, 28}}

Visualization:

```
Graphics[{
    Red, Point[Pick[pts, rmf@pts, False]],
    Blue, Point[Pick[pts, rmf@pts, True]],
    Black, RegionBoundary@Triangle[{{1,2},{3,5},{5,7}}]
}]
```

[image]

Sounds like you should ask this question on the Math StackExchange site. To get the relevant equations using Mathematica you could do:

```
RegionMember[Triangle[{{1,2},{3,5},{5,7}}], {x, y}]
```

> (x | y) ∈ Reals && -(5/2) (-1 + x) + 2 (-2 + y) >= 0 && 
>    2 + 3/2 (-1 + x) - y >= 0 && 3 - x + 2 (-2 + y) - y <= 1

Comment: In which language is this code written?

Comment: @CséfalvayBálint It is written in Mathematica of course. What do you expect on the Mathematica StackExchange site?

Comment: Then I chose a wrong side, because I need mathematical equation, or something like that.